# discord bot removing one role but not the rest

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So here's the bit I wrote to unassign roles. If I have multiple roles assigned it will remove the first one of them it finds, but then it breaks out of the loop somehow. I'm not sure why it isn't removing all of them. Any ideas? role_list is just a list of strings.

```
if message.content.startswith("!unassign"):
    roles_cleared = True

    for r in role_list:
        # Check every role
        role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=r)
        if role in message.author.roles:
            # If they have the role, get rid of it
            try:
                await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await client.send_message(message.author, "I don't have perms to remove roles.")
                roles_cleared = False
                break

    if roles_cleared:
        await client.send_message(message.author, "Roles successfully cleared.")
```

Comment: Are you sure it has the permission to remove all of them? The only `break` I can see here is in the `except` clause.

Comment: I'm the owner of the server and I authorized it with admin access. I also made sure the role was listed above all of the others in the list, and I'm definitely not hitting that break because I'm not receiving any permission error messages in the console or from the bot itself.

Comment: Also you forgot to mention whether the last line actually executes or not. If it doesn't then the `except` clause definitely executed because that's the only place we change the value of `roles_cleared`.

Comment: btw even admins can't touch roles which are above them in the hiearchy.

Comment: The last line executes just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a delay after each role removal. Just import asyncio and add an `await asyncio.sleep(1)`. Your code should look like:

```
if message.content.startswith("!unassign"):
    roles_cleared = True

    for r in role_list:
        # Check every role
        role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=r)
        if role in message.author.roles:
            # If they have the role, get rid of it
            try:
                await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await client.send_message(message.author, "I don't have perms to remove roles.")
                roles_cleared = False
                break

    if roles_cleared:
        await client.send_message(message.author, "Roles successfully cleared.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in itself looks fine, the only problem I can think of is if `role_list` only contains one string. You should check the part of the code that assigns it.

Also have you tried debugging it with a debugger such as PyCharm's one? This sounds like the type of problem that could use it.